# My server was used for sending spam. Will our server ever be trusted again?

Tags: email, spam

A while back I enabled SMTP on my IIS server with the intention of using it for internal email notifications. It seems that somehow hackers were able to use it for sending out thousands of spam messages.

We've corrected the issue by adding some authentication to the server, but we're no longer trusted by many email clients. I'm guessing they must just assume we're still sending out spam by our IP?

Will our "stigma" ever go away so that we may send emails that don't go straight to the spam box? IP addresses are recycled so I don't imagine we can just be blocked forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll forego the scolding about enabling SMTP on an IIS server -- I'm sure that you've already told yourself everything I could think of saying, possibly several times over -- and just focus on your current problem.

Most *reputable* spam blacklists these days have automated or semi-automated removal mechanisms in place already. You can just contact, say, spamhaus or spamcop and use the removal process on their websites to have your IP address provisionally removed from their blacklists.

**NOTE: DO NOT DO THIS IF YOU AREN'T CERTAIN YOU ACTUALLY DID CLOSE THE SPAM LOOPHOLE**. If you tell them you cleaned it up and they receive more spam, they'll automatically drop you into the "lied to us about having cleaned up his act" category and that one's harder to get out of.